# chrome APP : google maps, Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: google-chrome, maps, manifest, content-security-policy

I'm trying to include google map within my chrome **app** (not an extension, an **APP**).

When I launch the app, I see the following exception:
Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I know this is a content security policy issue, but the following line in my manifest file does not work:
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com; object-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'"

This works for an **extension**, but not for an app.
If I try to add this line in my app manifest, I get the following:
'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.

Does anybody had managed to include a google map view within a chrome application?

Answer (score 1):

You can't load external scripts within a Chrome Packaged Application. What you can do instead is to have an iframe in your main html document pointing to a sandboxed html document that can have the reference to the Google Maps script that you need (And also the #map div and the logic to initialize it).

See this example of a sandboxed html inside an iframe: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/sandbox

Also, be sure to check this document: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external in order to setup your manifest